# How do I access the quickblox session token when using Facebook login?

Tags: ios, facebook, quickblox

I have successfully logged into Facebook using:

```
[QBUsers logInWithSocialProvider:@"facebook" scope:@[@"publish_stream"] delegate:self];

-(void)completedWithResult:(Result*)result{
    //sign in
    if(result.success && [result isKindOfClass:[QBUUserLogInResult class]]){
        QBUUserLogInResult *loginResult = (QBUUserLogInResult *)result;

        //etc.
```

I have read that I need to set `loginResult.user.password` to the QB session token. How do I gain access to the session token?

Comment: I tried to make your title a bit more specific and clear so as to hopefully improve your chances of getting a specific answer - if I made a mistake in representing your issue, please correct it!

Answer (score 0):

If you need quickblox session token - use this:

```
 [QBBaseModule sharedModule].token
```

Actually I don;t understand why you need it ) Please provide additional info

If you need Facebook access token - use this:

```
[QBUsers logInWithSocialProvider:@"facebook" scope:@[@"publish_stream"] delegate:self];

-(void)completedWithResult:(Result*)result{
    //sign in
    if(result.success && [result isKindOfClass:[QBUUserLogInResult class]]){
        QBUUserLogInResult *loginResult = (QBUUserLogInResult *)result;

        NSLog(@"QBUUserLogInResult, user=%@, \n socialProviderToken=%@, \n
       socialProviderTokenExpiresAt=%@", res.user, 
       res.socialProviderToken, res.socialProviderTokenExpiresAt);

       ....
```

Comment: I am attempting to login to the QB Chat. I have tried several times to set the loginResult.user.password to the socialAccessToken and am getting a "notAuthorized" error. Would you mind helping me go through the steps of logging into the Chat with the code I currently have? Thanks.

Comment: yes, just set chatuser.password to [QBBaseModule sharedModule].token and will login to chat

Comment: in my case, would I set the loginResult.password to [QBBaseModule sharedModule].token? Thank you for your help Igor.